# In which way 'docker container commit' command helps in debugging?

Tags: docker

From [docks.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description):

> It can be useful to commit a container’s file changes or settings into a new image. **This allows you to debug a container by running an interactive shell**, or to export a working dataset to another server.

I can run an interactive shell on the existing container without creating new image with `docker container commit`.

Also, if we want separate container to not break anything in existing one, we can just run another container based on the image.

So, how `docker container commit` helps me to debug the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn’t use `docker commit`, ever.

Once upon a time Docker didn’t have `docker exec`.  The only thing you could do was to `docker run` a new container.  Usually you would want to set things up so that `docker build` sets up everything for you, and to debug things you could `docker run --rm -it myimage sh`, but if something really went wonky at runtime, in the absence of `exec`, the best you could do was commit the current state of the container and then run a new container with an interactive shell on the resulting image.

These days, as you say, `docker exec` is a better tool for live debugging.  (It is not intended to be the primary way you work with your container.)  If you need an image, `docker build` and the `Dockerfile` system is a more reproducible way to build images.